# SQL Update table rows where the is a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have the following table in SQL server.

[image: SQL table]

It is called ScenarioData and I am using the data specifically the fieldValue column to append this data into a form. I have achieved this functionality but unfortunately, the form requires a start date that has to be the present-day or up to 30 days in the future. Because I am storing data in the database as soon as the date passes these values are redundant. I have a stored procedure that selects all values from this table based on the scenarioDataId.

I was thinking to ensure that the date is always viable I could add to this stored procedure to update the relevant rows (coverStartDateDay, coverStartDateMonth, coverStartDateYear) with the current date so that the value will always be accepted.

I have proceeded the following SQL

```
UPDATE dbo.ScenarioData
SET ScenarioData.FieldValue = DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
WHERE ScenarioData.FieldName = "CoverStartDateDay";
```

This I had hoped would append the current day to the rows in feilfValue wherein the column fieldName it equals the value coverStartDateDay. Unfortunately, I get an error saying CoverStartDateDay is not a column. Firstly where am I going wrong and secondly how can I achieve the functionality I desire?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty simple syntaxerror. Just change your double quotes to single quotes and your good to go.

Comment: FYI, this looks liek very heavily denormalised data. YOu would be far better off with separate columns and using the correct data types. `(n)varchar` is not a "one size fits all" data type.

Comment: @Larnu Could you explain what you mean by denormalised data and also (n)varchar one size fits all please. thanks

Comment: You have a column that represents many things, a start date, a postcode, a house number, and those things are different data types, a `date`, an `int`, a `varchar`. Each should be it's own column, with the correct data type. This is a scenario where you should be building wide not tall.

Comment: Ok, i understand your point and I agree with it, but probably my bad for not adding context behind the reason I have this table. Everything in FeidlName is an id from a html form. I have created web extension that makes ajax calls with the web API which interfaces with the database. Because of this all data in FieldValue is representative of a html element id. For example Postcode is used and results in becoming '#Postcode'. I then use this to search a form and append the fieldValue data to the field, hence the data being a mixture of everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quote :

```
WHERE ScenarioData.FieldName = 'CoverStartDateDay';
```

In SQL Server double quotes are considers as column name. However, Double quotes have different usage depending on the setting `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`.

By default `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is enabled (`ON`) & you can't use it to enclose *literal* strings.

For instance, if you want to go with double  quotes then you need to disable `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
```

Comment: Thanks, that was such a simple mistake. Both yourself and Suraji Kumar gave me the fix for this so thank you to both

Answer (score 1):

Try this as `varchar` or `string` values should be passed in the single quote, not in the double quote.

```
UPDATE dbo.ScenarioData
SET ScenarioData.FieldValue = DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
WHERE ScenarioData.FieldName = 'CoverStartDateDay'
```

Double quotes are for identifiers. Somehow if you want to pass values which contain a single quote, then you can use `''` i.e., two times a single quote not the double quote.